How is Maya c++ plugin MPxNode unaffected by cache playback
I've developed a Maya C++ plugin based on MpxNode.  When adding attributes to my node and keyframing them, Maya's Cached Playback causes calculation errors in my plugin.  How can I prevent Cached Playback from disrupting my plugin's calculations after adding keyframes to attributes?
I've looked through some API documentation, but my English proficiency is limited, so I didn't find anything useful.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
